# How to bind the same topic to multiple functions with the Kafka Streams binder in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

With Spring Cloud Stream and the Kafka Streams binder, I would like to process the output of a function in another one, as in:

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, Double>, KStream<String, Double>> sqrt() {
    return numbers -> numbers.mapValues(Math::sqrt);
}

@Bean
public Consumer<KStream<String, Double>> log() {
    return sqrt -> sqrt.foreach((key, value) -> log.info("{}: {}", key, value));
}
```

where `sqrt()` outputs the square root of a number, which is then logged with `log()`. `application.yaml` therefore looks like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        bindings:
          sqrt-in-0: numbers
          sqrt-out-0: sqrt-numbers
          log-in-0: sqrt-numbers
      kafka:
        streams:
          bindings:
            sqrt:
              consumer:
                application-id: sqrtApplicationId
            log:
              consumer:
                application-id: logApplicationId
```

When starting the application, I get the following error:

```
The bean 'sqrt-numbers' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Now of course setting `definition-overriding` to `true` is not a proper fix, and it will fail with an `IllegalStateException`.

How do I solve this?

A reproduction of the problem can be found here: https://github.com/cedric-schaller/dltawareprocessor-type-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have two Kafka topics called, `numbers` and  `sqrt-numbers`, the following configuration should work.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        sqrt-in-0:
          destination: numbers
        sqrt-out-0: 
          destination: sqrt-numbers
        log-in-0: 
          destination: sqrt-numbers
      kafka:
        streams:
          bindings:
            sqrt-in-0:
              consumer:
                application-id: sqrtApplicationId
            log-in-0:
              consumer:
                application-id: logApplicationId
```

You can use `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings..` to override a default binding name. For example, if you want to change the binding name from `sqrt-in-0` to `input`, you can do it like `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.sqrt-in-0: input`. You still need to set `destination` on the overridden binding though (via `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination`).

The particular exception you are getting is because you are trying to reuse an already created binding name - `sqrt-numbers`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer; really appreciated! You might however want to correct what I believe to be a typo: `sqrt-in0-0` -> `sqrt-in-0`.